# Vue Transition inside the div element doesn't work

Tags: vue.js

Could someone explain me, why the following code doesn't work?

```
<template>
  <div class="modal">
    <transition name="slide-in">
      <div @click.stop class="modal__container">
        <div @click="close" class="modal__button">
          <span class="modal__button--close">Close</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
    <transition name="fade-in">
      <div @click="close" class="modal__overlay"/>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to create *modal* with two different animations (`slide-in` for text area and `fade-in` for modal overlay).

If i delete the element with class `modal` and edit code to the following everything works fine.

```
<template>
   <transition name="slide-in">
     <div @click.stop class="modal__container">
       <div @click="close" class="modal__button">
         <span class="modal__button--close">Close</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </transition>
</template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referencing Vue.js documentation on [transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

> Vue provides a variety of ways to apply transition effects when items are **inserted, updated, or removed** from the DOM

That means that DOM nodes that transition applies classes to, should be those which are inserted/updated/removed.

Since it is a modal window, I assume that it has `v-if` directive applied in parent component to handle it's visibility. In order for transition to work, it should wrap DOM element that will be updated.

You can understand it more easily if you move code of your modal window into the parent component. Just for better visualization of elements tree and transition's behavior.

In first example, conditional rendering (`v-if`) applies to `<div class="modal">`, which is not wrapped with transition - therefore no animation will be triggered. At the same time, nested nodes are wrapped with transition, but there is nothing that will update or remove them. They are statically displayed and inserted initially on component's creation. Nothing to animate.

In order for it to work as expected following structure would be advisable:

```html
<template> 
  <transition name="fade-in">
    <div 
      class="modal__overlay"
      @click="close"
    >
      <transition name="slide-in">
        <div 
          v-if="containerVisible"
          class="modal__container"
          @click.stop
        >
          <div @click="close" class="modal__button">
            <span class="modal__button--close">Close</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
```

This solution expects `modal__overlay` to have `position: fixed;` style and variable `containerVisible` to be set to `true` inside `mounted` hook of modal component.